# deep mongodb aggregate to make Groups with the common fields in array of objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I want to make the groups from this using mongodb aggregate. I want to immplement this on my project but stuck in this. not finding a better way to do this.

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e9a21868ed974259c0da402"),
    "shopId" : "5e975cc7be7c1b546b7abb17",
    "shopType" : "Medium Store",
        "products": [{
            "isPackedProduct" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e92ff706af877294d63098e"),
            "brand" : "ABC",
            "category" : "CAT1",
            "productName" : "P1",
            "subCategory" : "SUB1",
        },
        {
            "isPackedProduct" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e92ff706af877294d63098f"),
            "brand" : "EFG",
            "category" : "CAT1",
            "productName" : "P2",
            "subCategory" : "SUB2",
        },
        {
            "isPackedProduct" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e92ff706af84d630977298f"),
            "brand" : "EFG",
            "category" : "CAT2",
            "productName" : "P3",
            "subCategory" : "SUB1",
        }
        ....
     ]    
}
```

From this set of json i want to show the data as:

```js
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5e9a21868ed974259c0da402"),
     "shopId" : "5e975cc7be7c1b546b7abb17",
     "CAT1":{
       "SUB1":{
          "products": [{
            ...ALL the Products which have CAT1 and SUB1
          }]
        }
     },
     "CAT2":{
       "SUB1":{
          "products": [{
            ...ALL the Products which have CAT2 and SUB1
          }]
        }
     }
     ...
   }
```

i tried so far but not getting close to solution:

```js
db.shopproducts.aggregate([{$unwind: {path: '$products'}}, {$group: {_id: 'products.category'}}, {$project: {'products.category': 1, 'products.productName': 1}}])
```

Also, if there is a better way to do this without using aggregate then suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.shopproducts.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$products"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        cat: "$products.category",
        sub_cat: "$products.subCategory"
      },
      products: {
        $addToSet: "$products"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I guess this is what you want, isn't it?

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U1SR4jcQ3An)

Answer (score 1):

We need to apply several `$group` stages. To transform `products.category` and `products.subCategory` into object field, we need to use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) operator.

```
[                                        {
  { "k" : "CAT1", "v" : "SUB1" }, ----\     "CAT1" : "SUB1",
  { "k" : "CAT2", "v" : "SUB1" }  ----/     "CAT2" : "SUB1"
]                                        }
```

Try this one:

```
db.shopproducts.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$products"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        shopId: "$shopId",
        category: "$products.category",
        subCategory: "$products.subCategory"
      },
      products: {$push: "$products"}
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id._id",
        shopId: "$_id.shopId",
        category: "$_id.category"
      },
      products: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.subCategory",
          v: {products: "$products"}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id._id",
        shopId: "$_id.shopId"
      },
      products: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.category",
          v: {$arrayToObject: "$products"}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            shopId: "$_id.shopId"
          },
          {
            $arrayToObject: "$products"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vaCt0DeETEQ)